# Overwriting Messages with Same Correlation ID and Sequence Number in Spring

Tags: spring, sequence, spring-integration, correlation, aggregator

Based on my own experiments (can't find this documented anywhere), if 2 messages, having the same correlation ID and sequence number, aggregator will only take the 1st message and discard/ignore the other message.

Is there a way to make aggregator use the last message received instead?

The aggregation will merge the payload into 1 string.

Simple scenario:
3 messages with same correlation ID and sequence size of 2, ordered by time received

- sequence#: 1; payload: abc
- sequence#: 1; payload: def
- sequence#: 2; payload: ghi

Current output: abcghi

Expected output: defghi

This scenario happens when sequence# 2 is missing which is meant for the 1st message. And the correlation ID (obtained from decoded payload) is very limited, hence it will be used multiple times.

**Original message**

The raw messages came in this format:

- "Sequence Size","Sequence Number","ID","Text"
- ID ranges between 0-9
- example message: 2,1,8,abc

Sample raw message payload:

- 2,1,8,abc
- 2,1,8,def
- 2,2,8,ghi

The aggregator basically combine the text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a custom release strategy (it can have the same logic as the default `SequenceSizeReleaseStrategy`, but it can't be that class). With the default strategy duplicate sequences are skipped.

However, you will also need a custom message group store to enact your desired behavior; otherwise the output will be `abcdefghi`.

However, the discarded message will not be sent to the discard channel in that case.

It's generally not a good idea to reuse correlation id; if you must, then use the `group-timeout` or a reaper to discard the partial group before any possibility of reuse of the correlation id.

BTW, you might find it easier to use a custom `CorrelationStrategy` and `ReleaseStrategy` rather than using the default and manipulating the headers.

Comment: thanks gary!

as suggested, i'm currently figuring out on how to customize this (using non-default) mainly on the overwriting the messages with same sequence.


and FYI, yes its a must for my case to reuse the correlationId since it is derived from the message's payload which I can't manipulate.


I've used group-timeout, but it is not behaving as I have expected. You can refer to another question of mine here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30421220/group-timeout-does-not-work-as-expected-in-spring-aggregator/30424784


will update soon.

Comment: correct me if i'm wrong here, correlatestrategy is only to tell which message belongs to which group, and releasestragy is to tell when the grouped messages can proceed to next path. and my focus should be with the custom message group so that the message with same seq. number will overwrite the old one. Am I wrong?

Comment: by any chance you have a sample custom message group store?

Comment: ok found this:
http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/latest-ga/api/org/springframework/integration/store/SimpleMessageStore.html

Comment: As I said, it would be much better to time out the old group or come up with a better correlation strategy, rather than trying to manipulate an incomplete group within the message store.

Comment: added sample messages, showing why the correlation id is really limited. tried to time out the old group but doesn't seems to work. Some messages still go through (not all). So I thought it is because same sequence number could cause the timeout did not trigger.

Comment: Tried with custom message store.. By overiding the addMesageToGroup from SimpleMessageStore.. The 2nd message with same sequence number was not read. Is this expected? Cant find this info mentioned anywhere though

Comment: As I said; you must use a different release strategy to the standard `SequenceSizeReleaseStrategy` otherwise the second message will never be added to the group.

Comment: I've copied and modified the existing *SequenceSizeReleaseStrategy*, however, the 2nd (same sequence) message still did not go through..

Comment: Just so u know, i know the timeout works based on the discard channel.

Comment: Ok.. After further testing some went through.. I'll do more trsting n let u know