# Group Timeout does not work as expected in Spring Aggregator

Tags: spring-integration, aggregator

**Sample aggregator:**

```
<int:aggregator
    input-channel="msgInput"
    output-channel="msgOutput"
    expire-groups-upon-completion="true"
    group-timeout="1000"
    expire-groups-upon-timeout="true"
    send-partial-result-on-expiry="false"
    ref="msgGroup" 
/>
```

With sequence size of 2, when I manually iterate the timestamp of each messages grouped with msgGroup, there are still some (not all) messages that is more than 1000ms difference. Is there anything that I missed perhaps?

*Please note that the correlation ID and sequence number is set programmatically based on the payload. Hence, some messages could have same correlationID with sequence number.*

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you turn on debug logging and follow the message flows.

I am not sure what you mean by "manually iterate the timestamp". Group timeout has nothing to do with message timestamps; it's based on message arrival time (i.e. last group update time).

Comment: I've turned on debug, and compare the timestamps (from the headers) of each of the messages received which is grouped based on the correlationId that I manually set. In actual situation, I set the group-timeout to 10ms, and when I compare the timestamps of each of the message received, it differs to like 30 seconds sometimes.

should I instead print the current time exactly right before the messages hits the aggregator and compare from there instead?

Comment: As I said, the timeout is based on the time of the last message arrival and has nothing to do with the timestamps in the headers. "...should I print..." - exactly what are you trying to do? The group will timeout based on the last message arrival time.

Comment: by "print", i meant just to compare that some of the messages arrived did not trigger the group-timeout. most probably, as you've mentioned on my other question, due to the default behavior of the message group store. i'm trying to find the source of the default message group store, but couldn't find it. will let you know later.

Comment: I think you should take a step back and explain your use case so we can come up with a better solution than what you are attempting to achieve.

Comment: Well. I have to concerns to you: 1. You don't explain how it must work if you insist that it doesn't work properly. 2. You don't share the info what you need to do by business purpose. Please, read more docs on the matter to understand how it works. Actually we can come up with the solution for any task, but in that case we really should start from the goal, but not from any objection that it doesn't work, like you think.